# Dissconnect wallet function

Tags: reactjs, ethereum, solidity, web3js, metamask

here is my connect wallet function which is called when I click on connect wallet button

```
const connectWallet = async () => {
    if(window.ethereum){
     try{
       await window.ethereum.request({ method: "eth_requestAccounts"}).then(res=>{
        setAddress(res[0]);
        web3 = new Web3(window.ethereum)
        setWeb3(web3)
        const vm = AdmissionContract(web3)
        setVmContract(vm)       
       })
   }catch(err){
    setError(err.message)
   }
  }else{
    alert("install metamask extension!!")
  }}
```

Now I want a button which will call a function that disconnect this connected account

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I disconnect Metamask wallet using web3.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72716168/how-can-i-disconnect-metamask-wallet-using-web3-js)

Comment: No this is not helpful

Answer (score 0):

You have no control over metamask. You can have another button to set the address to null

```
<button onClick=(()=>setAddress(null)) >disconnect</button>
```

if you have buttons that interact with metamask except "connect button", maybe you "pay button" you have to disable by address flag. For example

```
<button disabled={address} >Pay</button>
```

If there is address set, you let your app interact with the metamask otherwise you disable it.